# Adding a region to the Omega template

Tags: theming

I am trying to add a new region to the Omega Hero template. I have duplicated the Hero template calling it SuperHero and this is working okay. ( I have created a sub-theme ).

In the tpl file I have added the new bottom_sidebar region:

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
<?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
<?php print render($page['sidebar_bottom']); ?>
```

In the .inc file I have added the region here:

```
regions[sidebar_first]  = First sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Second sidebar
regions[sidebar_bottom] = Bottom sidebar
regions[footer]         = Footer
```

I have create new stylesheets and they are working okay but the new sidebar isn't appearing in the HTML.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you assigned any blocks to the region?

Comment: The region isn't appearing on the structure/blocks page at all. I have trawled a fair bit to try to find if I am missing something but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out from this post here drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100102/… that I was overlooking the theme.info file in the themes root directory:

```
regions[sidebar_first]  = First sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Second sidebar
regions[sidebar_bottom] = Bottom sidebar
regions[footer]         = Footer
```

Works perfectly now. There are *three* steps to adding a region to the Omega template.